# Is there a way to add out of the box actions to visual force pages?

Tags: visualforce, contact

I have a custom visual force page for the Contact object. On the contact object's 'Buttons, Links, and Actions' I can create an action that logs a call. Is there a way to add that action to the custom visual force page?

It seems like the Case object has a method that works but I can't seem to find a way for Contact.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" showHeader="true">
            <apex:logCallPublisher id="myLogCalllPublisher" 
                entityId="{!case.id}"          
                title="Log a Call"
                width="500px"
                autoCollapseBody="false"
            />  
        </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Chatter component for Visualforce page. It has ability to show publisher actions. Below are some referencese from Salesforce documentation :

- [Chatter feed Component](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm)
- [Chatter component for Visualforce pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter11/Chatter+Components+for+Visualforce)